# Scully isn't generating config.ts file in Angular project

Tags: angular, configuration, scullyio

I have a basic portfolio I'm building in Angular. I've successfully added Scully to the node_modules directory by running `ng add @scullyio/init@2.0.0`.

I'm using Scully for the first time, but everything I'm reading on it says a config.ts file is automatically generated. I'm not seeing it anywhere in my project directory.

When I try to create a blog by running `$ ng generate @scullyio/init:blog`, an unhandled exception happens:  `No scully configuration file found scully.undefined.config.ts Path "/scully.undefined.config.ts" does not exist.`

Any ideas why the file isn't being created? I even tried manually configuring but still get the same unhandled exception. Thanks for the considertation!

Answer (score 3):

This was an incredibly miniscule thing that took me forever to figure out (two working days!)... it was quite a frustrating journey. I am so happy I persisted. The feeling is similar a productive bowel movement. I imagine mentally like giving birth.

My usual googling/stackoverflowing was yielding scant results. The few gems I sifted out weren't working. I eventually found a casual mention on the scully chat forum. Sorry just wanted to document this effort. If you are having the same problem (nothing happening after executing ng add scully, here's what you do:

- go to angular.json and make sure there's a "defaultProject":"" above "projects" object.

  ```
   `"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
   "version": 1,
   "newProjectRoot": "projects",
   // ADD HERE ==== >
   /// "defaultProject": "portfolio2022_",
   "projects": {
   "portfolio2022_": {
   "projectType": "application",
   "schematics": {
     ...`
  ```

Comment: Angular deprecated the `defaultProject` key, and it might be a bad idea to keep using it unless there are other solutions. https://github.com/scullyio/scully/issues/1622#issuecomment-1266186975